# SELECT DISTINCT los elementos de ORDER BY deben aparecer en la lista de selección

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me da el error:

SELECT DISTINCT los elementos de ORDER BY deben aparecer en la lista de selección

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT  
(RIGHT('00000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Grupo)), 5) + RIGHT('000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SubGrupo)), 3)) AS Grupo, SubGrupo, NombreSubGrupo  
FROM DBTABLA 
ORDER BY Grupo + 0
```

Comment: Al verlo parece que es debido al +0 en el order by, ya que al hacer la operación lo detecta que es diferente a la columna Grupo sin la suma, aunque quede igual. Puedes sacar el +0 del order o añadirlo a Grupo en el select. Falta información para ayudar en caso de que no desaparezca.

Comment: @rexxarcat la columna Grupo es un string que debe ordenar como numero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he resuelto así:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
( 
    RIGHT('00000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Grupo)), 5) + 
    RIGHT('000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SubGrupo)), 3 ) 
) AS Grupo, NombreSubGrupo 
FROM DBTABLA 
ORDER BY Grupo
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es claro.

> Cuando se especifica SELECT DISTINCT, los elementos de ORDER BY deben
> aparecer en la lista de selección.

`Grupo + 0` no existe en la lista de select.

```
Select  
    d.Grupo, 
    d.SubGrupo,
    d.NombreSubGrupo
From (
    SELECT DISTINCT
            (RIGHT('00000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Grupo)), 5) + RIGHT('000' + LTRIM(RTRIM(SubGrupo)), 3)) AS Grupo 
            , SubGrupo
            , NombreSubGrupo  
            , Cast(grupo As Int) + 0 as colOrder
        FROM DBTABLA
)
as d
ORDER BY colOrder
```

Al utilizar una tabla derivada, en esta no aplica el `distinct`, y puedes ordenar por el criterio que te parezca apropiado.